# Updating and deleting user information from a list

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

Basically what I would like assistance with is essentially how can I delete, or update user information which gets displayed in a table when an administrator views a list of users.

What I need to really know is how I can get the user's values based on each individual table row. So far I have something like this: a list of users is showed using JSTL like

```
<td>
    <a href="<c:url value="/deleteUser"><c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></c:url>">
        <button>Delete User</button>
    </a>
</td>
```

This code snippet shows the table when the administrator views the 'listUsers' page. My controller then has something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/deleteUser")
public String deleteUser(@RequestParam(value = "id", required= false) Integer id) {
    usersService.delete(id);
    return "users";
}
```

It works, although it is buggy. I want to know the proper implementation method, on how to do this functionality properly.

Comment: There is a spring:url tag you can use to define a URL based on it's short URI name, and it prepends the proper beginning part.  You can even set a VAR.  I like this method better than putting tags inside of attributes of tags, because that gets confusing and makes the Editors go nutz.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax for such calls.
when user clicks on "Delete User", a javascript function can be called that reads userId from some attribute (like name attribute of anchor tag) and then calls controller.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@RequestMapping("/deleteUser/{userId}")
public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer userId) {
    usersService.delete(id);
}
```

Now you can check the response status of your ajax call, if its success remove the user row
you can also use jquery for making ajax call, it makes life simpler.